# Automatic task in NodeJS/Firebase

Tags: node.js, facebook, firebase

I have some functions in Firebase (with NodeJS) to make a post on Facebook. After an hour, I need to get the current status of this publication automatically.
Is there any way to activate a task that makes the query to Facebook in exactly one hour after having made the publication?

Comment: You may want to have a look at https://bunkat.github.io/later/

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way to do that would be with the `setTimeout()` method. I'm not experienced with firebase, but here's some pseudocode on how it might be done.

```
// Create facebook post
var post = createPost();
setTimeout(function() {
    // Code to execute in one hour
    post.getInformation();
}, 3600);
```

Comment: This won't work with code running in Cloud Functions.